# How to take a backup of coredata when the user uninstalls the application and restore it back when he installs the application again in ios

Tags: ios, core-data, backup, database-restore

How to achieve the above. I dont want multi device sync. I just want to save the coredata and to restore it when the user re installs the application. Which the best approach and can anyone please provide the links. I've tried with iCloud and it is mainly used for multi device sync.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

You'd need a web service to do this, I recommend Parse.com, all you'd need to do is create a dictionary of your data store and parse will create tables for you automatically. (unless there is a way to save the data to the iOS documents directory that would persist after a delete)

Comment: @Haplo Are u sure this cannot be achieved using iCloud?

Comment: Yes, in iOS 8 and above - but this limits your data to the iOS platform